# Android Stock Browser - Not responding to class changes

Tags: javascript, android, css, browser, android-webview

For my web-page, things work fine on Android API level 21.

But when I test the same page against Android API level 18, some features do not work.

When I toggle class "check" on .div1 with javascript. The .div2 display is not updated.

Here is sample HTML and sample CSS

HTML

```
<div class="div1 check"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>

<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```

CSS
    .div2{ display: none;}
    .div1.check ~ .div2{ display: block;}

Again, this works fine in Android API level 21 but facing issues in Android API level 18.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noticed as I change the device orientation the stock browser appears to have repainted the page and all the CSS worked.

So in order to force repaint the screen through code, I wrote a small util function which is

```
    function _repaintPage() {
      $("body").hide().show();
      $("body").removeAttr("style");
    }
```